# Fullcalendar V6: call a hook with another hook

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-6

I am adding some custom html to a resource timeline if there are no events for that week. It works on initial page load, but when `next` or `prev` buttons are clicked, it needs to be initiated again. I have found the proper way to do this in version 6, is to use `datesSet`.

However, I can't figure out how to call `resourceLandDidMount` whenever `datesSet` is fired. Here is the function I need to run with `dateSet`:

```
resourceLaneDidMount : function(arg){
  if(arg.el.classList.contains('fc-timeline-lane')){
    var theElement = arg.el.querySelectorAll('.fc-timeline-lane-frame > .fc-timeline-events')[0]
    setTimeout(function(){
      if(theElement.querySelectorAll('.fc-timeline-event-harness').length > 0) {
        console.log('has event harness class');
      } else {
        console.log('has no event harness class');
      }
    })
  }
},
```

Comment: You can't "call" a hook. A hook is something which is called _by fullcalendar_ in response to a certain event happening within the calendar. What your code is doing is providing a function which fullCalendar can call whenever it decides it's necessary. So if pressing prev/next doesn't cause the resource Lanes to be re-mounted, then the resourceLaneDidMount event won't occur, and the hook function won't be called. That's not something you can affect (unless you want to change the internal fullCalendar code, which I really wouldn't recommend).

Comment: However, since this code appears to just work by finding elements with certain classes, I'm sure you could refactor it so there wasn't a dependency on the `arg.el` variable (e.g. you could just search the whole calendar element for that class instead). And then if you put that code which updates all the fc-timeline-lane elements into an independent function, you can call it from anywhere.